# Get the current URL inside the custom functions of an Excel JS Office-Add-In

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js, office-addins, custom-function

I want to open a dialog from the custom functions and since I don't want to hard code the location of that dialog, I need the location of the currently running add-in to dynamically create the URL for the dialog.

For Office-online window.location works perfectly fine, but inside the desktop version where a special run time is used this isn't available. How can I achieve that? Is there another object to get the location from or is there a way to receive information from the manifest file dynamically?

thx for your time

Comment: Did you try the `document.url` which should return the url along with the host_info

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but unfortunately this doesn't work as well inside this special run time

Comment: What do you mean special runtime ? I have checked on my desktop version which works really fine

Comment: Desktop version of what? Custom functions in Excel Office JS add-ins use a new JavaScript runtime that differs from the runtime used by other parts of an add-in, it is designed to optimize performance of calculations in custom functions [...]  In Excel on Windows, where custom functions use the JavaScript runtime, custom functions cannot access the DOM.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/excel/custom-functions-runtime.md

There are limitations I know and I have ideas for workarounds, but I would prefer to get the URL without a lot un maybe unnecessary effort

Answer (score 1):

custom functions currently do not have access to the apis. We are working to expose access to office.js directly but for now, you will have to get this property from your taskpane on initialization and then store it in officeruntime.storage, then you can retrieve it from your custom functions.

Feature for office.js support is being worked on and tracked here: 
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Custom-Functions/issues/130

Thanks

Comment: thanks for the confirmation, that's unfortunately the answer I expected. I will have to use the solution for now but I don't like it because of course a formula could be used before the task pane was opened the first time... and if one might switch the usage of the same add in from different locations it might get a bit confusing